# Soundmanager2 Adding Image like Souncloud (waveform img)

Tags: image, soundcloud, soundmanager2

Yestoday I finished making all my Waveform PNG images :)
Today I tried to make a connection between the image and the Soundmanager player.. with no luck
I want to add the image as a background to each song listed just like soundcloud but I just cant ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it as a fixed background image in css?
Then put an progressbar on top of it with opacity as 0.2(?) or something, so it looks like its "progressing". Assuming your images are in grey like on soundcloud. If you have 2 images, you dont need the opacity obviously. Just make sure both images are the same size, and start in the same position. set the background width: 100%, and the progress image process/duration*100%

Unless your actual question is, how do i get the current time, duration of the song that is playing.